# How to write data to XML in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I am new To C# and XML

How can I write `Id`, `name`, `AvailProducts` and `Cost` with new values to an XML file in `C#`?

```
 <root>
<Bathing>
    <Id>San100</Id>
    <name>Santoor</name>
    <AvailProducts>30</AvailProducts>
    <Cost>20.00</Cost>
</Bathing>
<Bathing>
    <Id>Det123</Id>
    <name>Dettol</name>
    <AvailProducts>30</AvailProducts>
    <Cost>15.00</Cost>
</Bathing>
<Bathing>
    <Id>Rex123</Id>
    <name>Rexona</name>
    <AvailProducts>30</AvailProducts>
    <Cost>16.00</Cost>
</Bathing>
</root>
```

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried?

Comment: Have you read answers of your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/a/12740368/932418 ? It can be a good place to start

Comment: possible duplicate of [How i insert data into xml file using Windows Application in .net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403377/how-i-insert-data-into-xml-file-using-windows-application-in-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As everyone else said, you should have first try to find answer by searching in Google or even stackflow itself might have guided you.

Anyway,

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument(); 
xDoc.Load("XMLFile.xml")");  
XmlNodeList nodeList; 
nodeList = xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Bathing");

foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)

{

XmlNode child = node.SelectSingleNode("Id");

child.InnerText = "NewValue";

..write for other child nodes...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `XMLDocument` and use the `CreateNode` method.

```
  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(); 

  doc.LoadXml(); // file path of the XML you provided in your question.

  XmlNode nameElem = doc.CreateNode("element", "Name", "");  
  nameElem.InnerText = "Darren Davies";

  XmlNode availableProducts = doc.CreateNode("element", "AvailProducts", "");  
  availableProducts.InnerText = "Product";

  XmlNode cost = doc.CreateNode("element", "Cost", "");  
  cost.InnerText = "Cost";

  XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;

  root.AppendChild(nameElem); // Append the new name element
  root.AppendChild(availableProducts);
  root.AppendChild(cost);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162365.aspx#Y1700

Comment: that will add new node, the requirement I think is new values for existing nodes are to be saved.